# Extract list of users (millions) in Active Directory using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We have an Active Directory with 5 millions of users. We're getting the error "Get-ADUser : This operation returned because the timeout period expired" when trying to extract users using powershell script.

Already tried searching the web for an optimized script. Below is what we have. This works fine for ~500k users.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "CN=Users,DC=*****,DC=*****,DC=*****" -Server "*****" -ResultPageSize 1 -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=User)(whenCreated>=20190101000000.0Z)(whenCreated<=20190131235959.0Z))" -Properties WhenCreated | Select-Object Name, WhenCreated

$Users | Export-Csv C:\Temp\January2019.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Why are you setting `ResultPageSize` to `1`?? With that many users I rather would crank the defaultvalue of 256 up to [Int32]::MaxValue (2147483647). See [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps#optional-parameters)

Comment: I already tried changing the value of it to 100/500/1000 and also not using the ResultPageSize but still i got the error.

Comment: try adsisearcher instead and ResultPage Size like 200 or less up to 100

Comment: Does it work if you pipe Get-ADuser direct to the csv instead of storing it in a variable? You could also try increasing the memory available to powershell: http://vmwareinsight.com/Tips/2016/6/5798868/How-to-Configure-Maximum-Powershell-Memory-MaxMemoryPerShellMB-in-Windows-Server

Comment: Your organization probably has many sub OUs inside the `Users` OU. Perhaps it would be better to create an array of these sub OUs and loop through them one at a time, adding to the CSV file as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. Instead of using Get-ADUser, I was able to extract users using CSVDE (an LDIFDE variant that allows exporting data to CSV files) without any problem.

```
CSVDE -f D:\Temp\ADUseru.csv -d "CN=Users,DC=*****,DC=*****,DC=*****" -r "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(whenCreated>=20120101000000.0Z)(whenCreated<=20121231235959.0Z))" -l "name, whenCreated, memberOf, sAMAccountName"
```

Answer (score 2):

`Get-ADUser` and all the other cmdlets that PowerShell makes available to you are convenient, but horrible when it comes to performance.

You're better off using .NET's [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher), which PowerShell has a short-hand for: `[ADSISearcher]`. It's more code, yes, but it's *much* faster. Here's an example that should do what you want (make sure to change the first two lines for your OU and server):

```
$server = "****"
$ou = "CN=Users,DC=*****,DC=*****,DC=*****"

$searcher = [ADSISearcher]"(&(objectCategory=User)(whenCreated>=20190101000000.0Z)(whenCreated<=20190131235959.0Z))"
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("whenCreated") #We only want the whenCreated attribute
$searcher.PageSize = 200 #Get the users in pages of 200
$searcher.SearchRoot = [ADSI]"LDAP://$server/$ou"

$ADObjects = @()
[array]$ADObjects = foreach($result in $searcher.FindAll()) {
    # The SearchResultCollection doesn't output in PowerShell very well, so here we create
    # a PSObject for each results with the properties that we can export later

    [Array]$propertiesList = $result.Properties.PropertyNames
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    foreach($property in $propertiesList) { 
        $obj | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name $property -value ([string]$result.Properties.Item($property))
    }
    $obj
}

$ADObjects | Export-Csv C:\Temp\January2019.csv -NoTypeInformation
```